# CSS - positioning an absolute div to float vertically and horizontally

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to replicate my own version of the jQuery tooltip using only css, but I'm having trouble getting the vertical positioning right.

This is what I'm trying to get it to look like (Floating above the text):

[image]

Below is the code I'm currently using.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 5em;
  width: 70%;
  color: white;
}
body,
html {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  color: orange;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.linkhover {
  display: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  max-width: 300px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #aaa;
}
a:hover .linkhover {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  So I was browsing things on <a href='#'>stackoverflow <div class='linkhover'>A great place to get help with code!</div></a> a while ago and I noticed some pretty funny comments about jQuery!
</div>
```

I've also tried using

```
.linkhover{
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

But that effects every single link, I plan on using this for multiple links on the same page.

Any idea how I can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would, But fiddle is currently down.

Comment: You can edit your question and use the code snippet (Ctrl+M) feature...

Comment: @LcSalazar Oh my. i never noticed this. amazing

Comment: I've already marked a correct answer, But I edited in the "Run code Snippet" thing anyway ^^  
Thanks @LcSalazar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the positioning work accordingly with parent. Set `position:relative` on the parent:

```
.wrapper{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 5em;
  width: 70%;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the tooltip in a container and position it relatively. Then position the tooltip absolutely. Give the container a negative offset and adjust the positioning.

```css
.wrapper{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 5em;
  width: 70%;
  color: white;
}
body,html{
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a{
  color: orange;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.linkhover{
  display: none;
  background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  max-width: 300px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #aaa;
}
span#tooltipContainer {
  position: relative;
  left: -100px;
  top: -30px;
}
a:hover .linkhover{
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline;
  
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
    So I was browsing things on <a href='#'>stackoverflow <span id="tooltipContainer"><div class='linkhover'>A great place to get help with code!</div></span></a> a while ago and I noticed some pretty funny comments about jQuery!
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great way to do it, Thanks @chipChocolate.py!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, But I just remembered I can use negative margins.
Along with [bhojendra-c-link-nepal's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2138752/bhojendra-c-link-nepal) answer and a few negative margins, I got this result:

```css
.wrapper{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 5em;
  width: 70%;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
body,html{
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a{
  color: orange;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.linkhover{
  display: none;
  background: rgba(200,200,200, 0.9);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;
  padding: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  max-width: 300px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #aaa;
  margin-top: -35px;
  margin-left: -170px;
}
a:hover .linkhover{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
    So I was browsing things on <a href='#'>stackoverflow <div class='linkhover'>A great place to get help with code!</div></a> a while ago and I noticed some pretty funny comments about jQuery!
</div>
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but it seems to work.
Thanks for the help ^^